# grep words with all vowels in any order

Tags: regex, grep

Essentially I want to know if there is a way to represent the following in a single grep command :

```
grep "a" words.txt | grep "e" | grep "o" | grep "i" | grep "u"
```

Find all words with all 5 vowels in them, in any order.

The only method I can think of is to list all possible combinations, which is really really cumbersome.

Comment: Pretty the same: [find words with all vowels in order from a file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149171/40596)

Comment: @fedorqui, "in order" is different than "in any order"

Comment: @fedorqui My question is to find them in 'any' order,not aeiou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this to check for all vowels:

```
awk '/a/ && /e/ && /i/ && /o/ && /u/' words.txt
```

OR you can use `grep -P` to simplify it using lookahead regex:

```
grep -P "(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^e]*e)(?=[^i]*i)(?=[^o]*o)(?=[^u]*u)" words.txt
```

Comment: Could you explain what `-P` flag means exactly?

Comment: `-P` flag is used in modern `grep` for PCRE regex capability.

Comment: why have you used a negative class? if `(?=[^a]*a)` then `(?=.*a)`

Comment: @Bohemian: Just for efficiency purpose otherwise `(?=.*a)` is more readable.

Comment: efficiency is not as important as readability, but if you care, just `(?=.*?a)` should have similar performance (better?) than `(?=[^a]*a)` and is certainly more readable.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. It just prints a help description of grep after I press enter

Comment: @Venkat: Does your `grep` support `-P`? Check `man grep` if it doesn't then use my suggested `awk` command

Comment: @Bohemian: Not the first time I am having this discussion on comparing negation vs non-greedy performance. Check 2 links and click on `regex debugger` in both. [Link 1 with `(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^e]*e)(?=[^i]*i)(?=[^o]*o)(?=[^u]*u).*`](http://regex101.com/r/vF4zR5/1) and then [Link 2 with `(?=.*?a)(?=.*?e)(?=.*?i)(?=.*?o)(?=.*?u).*`](http://regex101.com/r/lA2cP3/1). You will note lazy quantifier is taking almost 3x more steps to do same thing.

Comment: Interesting. I just wrote a little test harness in java to compare *actual* performance of the two, because I thought that `.` would be faster to compare than `[^a]`. My test data was 10K shuffled alphabets. When the input was only 13 random letters, version 1 (`(?=[^a]*a)` etc) was about 50% *slower*, when all 26 letters were used, version 2 was about 10% slower, when longer input was used version 2 was about 20% slower. Overall, the performance was about the same, with the `(?=.*?a)` version out-performing with shorter input, and the `(?=[^a]*a)` version giving marginal gain for longer input